# In tensorflow serving, how to store a list in feature dictionary?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm pretty new with tensorflow serving, now I'm working with client-end coding.

With the basic tutorial, I know I need to build a feature dictionary like:

```
feature_dict={
    'input_content':tf.train.Feature(...)
    'input_label':tf.train.Feature(...)
}
```

Then,

```
model_input=tf.train.Example(feature=tf.train.Features(feature=feature_dict))
```

Now, my question is, how can I put a list into the feature_dict?
Like, I have a 10 dimension list, I want to set it as the 'input_content', how can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `tf.train.Feature` contains lists which may hold *zero or more* values. The lists could be of type `BytesList, FloatList,` or `Int64List`.

The following code adds a single float element (`float_element`) to the `tf.train.Feature`

`tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[float_element]))`

Notice that the `float_element` is surrounded by square brackets (`[]`), i.e., a list is being created with a single element.
While trying to add a list (`float_list`), one should not use square brackets like the following code snippet.

`tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=float_list))`